# Redirect to Same Visual Force Tab

Tags: visualforce, tab

Am using `<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="Survey" >` and have 2 tabs in them as:

```
<apex:tab label="Survey" name="Survey" id="Survey"></apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Visit Types Mapping" name="VisitMapping" id="VisitMapping"></apex:tab>
```

Now, I have a  save button in the "Visit Types Mapping"  tab .Whenever I click on save the the page is getting redirected to the default selected tab that is "Survey". My functionality demands to stay on the same tab i.e, "VisitMapping" tab.

Comment: Did you try to add `onclick="return false;"` on your button to prevend the redirection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change switch type to server:

```
<apex:tabPanel switchType="server" selectedTab="Survey" >
```

Also on "Save" button click, `rerender` the tab panel. It will prevent reload or redirection of page.

Another approach (set controller variable):

```
<apex:tabPanel switchType="server" selectedTab="{!selectedTab}" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is to NOT re-render the `apex:tabPanel` by e.g. only re-rendering the save button:

```
 <apex:commandButton id="me" value="Save" action="{!save}" rerender="me"/>
```

The `switchType="client"` can then remain; depending on what is in your tabs `switchType="server"` can be sluggish.